# What will trigger viewDidLayoutSubviews and look for a good pattern for initing subviews frame

Tags: ios

I have an app that is combined with autolayout from Storyboard, and some old, pure-code views don't have autolayout

In my MainViewController, I tried to initialize the subviews like bounds, constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewWillAppear. Because autolayout issue, and I found doing the initialization in viewDidLayoutSubviews is the best place to get the correct bounds for parent view's bounds.

However, I notice viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called 2-3 times before totally settle down, so I have to deal with if it is my first time to initialize my subviews, or update my frame if some constraints changed or size changed after autolayout.

Now I want to improve it, but I cannot figure out what's calling viewDidLayoutSubviews several times.

The best thing I want is that only one viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called, and after this I can get the correct size to initiaize my subviews.

I tried searching but some people saying viewDidLayoutSubviews is called by system, so no guarantee for how many times it will be called. If this is the case, what is the proper pattern to do initialization with autolayout subviews?

Answer (score 5):

`viewDidLayoutSubiews` is called multiple times during the creation of your viewController - once per run loop on any view that has had `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplayWithRect:` called on it, but also afterwards, in cases like rotating the device, scrolling etc. See this [link for more details](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/).

Basically, it is called each time your main view's layout changes, so you should be really careful with the code you add to this method, because it might be executed multiple times as well.

Comment: My problem is some old code from the project is doing pure code initialization, so it needs accurate size, but until the view controller layout settles down, I have no chance to get the correct size. Is there any way that I can know if the auto layout all finished so I can get the correct size and start initializing my subviews?

Comment: Put some logs in your viewDidLoad, viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and see when's the last moment your views' sizes change.

Comment: the last one is view did layout，that is why i am frustrated

Comment: does viewWillAppear get called afterwards? if so, you can initialise your views there.

Comment: No, willAppear first, then several layout calls, DidLayout among the DidLayout calls